# How can i build this kind of table?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a task that prints html pages into pdf, I am struggling in building this table footer. Colspan and other functions are not working and it destroys the table.

[image]

What I got is this one

[image]

```html
<table class="floating simpletable" border style="width: 100%">
  <col width=100>
  <col width=100>
  <col width=100>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="12" style="border-top-style: hidden;"></td>
      <td colspan="10">図番</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="12" style="border-top-style: hidden;"></td>
      <td colspan="10">{{$record->workname}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="12" style="border-top-style: hidden;"></td>
      <td style="border-top-style: hidden" colspan="10">購入仕様書（SES契約）</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="12" style="border-top-style: hidden;"></td>
      <td style="border-top-style: " colspan="8">仕様書図番</td>
      <td colspan="2">SHT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="1">版数</td>
      <td colspan="5">年月日</td>
      <td colspan="1">発行</td>
      <td colspan="2">記事</td>
      <td colspan="2">承認</td>
      <td colspan="1"></td>
      <td style="border-right-style: hidden" colspan="12">1/2</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="1">発行</td>
      <td colspan="1">{{$record->createdate1}}</td>
      <td colspan="2">{{$record->sdc_manager_name}}</td>
      <td colspan="5"></td>
      <td colspan="1">承認</td>
      <td colspan="1">承認</td>
      <td colspan="1">{{$record->sdc_manager_name}}</td>

      <td colspan="1">{{$record->sesnum1}}</td>
      <td colspan="1">001</td>
      <td colspan="1">2010</td>
      <td colspan="1">~</td>
      <td colspan="1">2101</td>
      <td colspan="4">1/2/
        <td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my jsfiddle so you can test it. (make sure to maximize the output of the window) https://jsfiddle.net/ho3rsngy/1/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with the `col` elements, but mostly you just need to get all your rows having the same number of columns. I see some with 22 and at least one with 24 and one with 21. They need to match so that every column is represented in every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```css
.sample-table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
}
.sample-table td{
    border: 1px solid #000; 
}
```

```html
<table class="sample-table">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="10" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="4">text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">text<br>
      text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">text</td>
    <td>SHT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text11</td>
    <td>text12</td>
    <td>text13</td>
    <td colspan="4">colspan 4</td>
    <td colspan="2">colspan 2</td>
    <td>empty</td>
    <td rowspan="2">KW-SEK</td>
    <td rowspan="2">001</td>
    <td rowspan="2">2010 ~ 2101</td>
    <td rowspan="2">1/2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text21</td>
    <td>2020/3/31</td>
    <td colspan="2">colspan 2</td>
    <td>text24</td>
    <td>empty</td>
    <td colspan="2">colspan 2</td>
    <td colspan="2">colspan 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for this one sir. Thanks for your effort for making this one.